# Combobox returns null when value is typed

Tags: c#, combobox, null, selectedvalue

Sorry if it has some obvious solution, but I am trying to solve it for hours but could not find a solution.

I use several `ComboBox`es in my `WindowsFormsApplication` to relate `id`s with `name`s. The problem is that when a user select an item from the combobox list, it works fine, but when he ***types*** an item, the `SelectedValue` property of the combobox is `null`.

To simulate the problem, I created a from with one button and a combobox. 
In my actual application, I populate the comboboxes with data from tables in a sqlserver database, but for simplicity, here I populate it with a `list`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<KeyValuePair<short,short>> l = new List<KeyValuePair<short,short>>();
    l.Add(new KeyValuePair<short,short>(1,10));
    l.Add(new KeyValuePair<short,short>(2,20));
    l.Add(new KeyValuePair<short,short>(3,30));
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = l;
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.comboBox1.SelectedValue == null)
        MessageBox.Show("NULL");
    else
        MessageBox.Show(this.comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

For example, when user select the second item (20) from the list and clicks on the button, messagebox shows *2* as it is expected, but if he types the number *20* into the combobox, the `SelectedValue` is `null`.

This problem could be solved by changing the style of combobox:

```
this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

But it prevents user to type into the combobox, so I am forced to use the default `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the combo box does not select the item that you have typed. Add this option

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
```

Then it will select the item when ever it was able to find it.

By default it is set to `AutoCompleteMode.None`.

(I think) This is mainly designed for suggestions but it can solve your problem here. also if you want to show the suggestions:

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

by default it is set to `AutoCompleteSource.None`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

An option that you have is using the EventHandler on the comboBox1.TextChange event that will allow you to personally handle how the text is translated into the different options.

This can be added to the designer (similar to a button).

`this.comboBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.UpdateValue);`

Then depending on how want to read the results and see if you have a match you can create a converter, use another key/value, or you can do a boring old tryparse as I will show you. You will need the list as a property that you can reference to see if you have found the proper results.

```
private void UpdateValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    short result;
    if (short.TryParse(comboBox1.Text, out result))
    {
        var matches = from val in l where val.Value == result select val.Key;
        {
            foreach (short m in matches)
                this.comboBox1.SelectedValue = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck! Let me know if you need more examples with the event handler. Don't forget to vote.